# Web worker that works on Firefox throws strange error on google chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, web-worker

In my web worker I have a line where I set the `onmessage` handler like so:

```
onmessage = function() {/*...*/}
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but in google chrome I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onmessage is not defined
```

So what is wrong with my code example?

Comment: have you defined onmessage before, like `var onmessage;`? If it is not intended to be a variable did you tried to define it like `function onmessage() { }`? - I personally thiink youre having problems with js syntax

Comment: there is no other onmessage function on the file, I tired declaring onmessage with `var onmessage = ...` but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `self.onmessage` appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
    onmessage = function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  ... 
};
```

Or check if your browser supports Webworkers [CanIuse Webworker](http://caniuse.com/#search=webworker)

Comment: this is the same as my example